# Creating a report from label values in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, report

I have a website that I wrote in ASP.net and I have a page called Statistics.aspx 
that I displayed few useful numbers that admin can view in labels . 
I want to make a button " Download Report " that can put these numbers into a word/pdf document .
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a bit more detail.Well I believe this is useful

```
string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine(Label1.text); // and so on

    using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\AllTxtFiles.txt"))
    {
        outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
```